# How do stable functions 1 => 1 relate to Bool?

Tags: lambda-calculus, semantics

One way to interpret the (simply typed) lambda calculus is via coherence spaces ([Proofs and Types, chapter 8](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/Proofs+Types.html)).  For example, we can consider the space containing token element ($\mathbf{1}$) and the space containing two incoherent tokens ($\mathbf{Bool}$).  These are given as follows:

$$
  \mathbf{1} = \{\emptyset, \{0\}\}\\
  \mathbf{Bool} = \{\emptyset, \{t\}, \{f\}\}
$$

We can then consider the stable functions from $\mathbf{1}$ to itself:

$$
    F_1(\emptyset) = \emptyset, F_1(\{0\}) = \emptyset\\
    F_2(\emptyset) = \emptyset, F_2(\{0\}) = \{0\}\\
    F_3(\emptyset) = \{0\}, F_3(\{0\}) = \{0\}
$$

The trails of these functions are as follows:

$$
    \mathcal{Tr}(F_1) = \emptyset\\
    \mathcal{Tr}(F_2) = \{(\{0\}, 0)\}\\
    \mathcal{Tr}(F_3) = \{(\emptyset, 0)\}
$$

This again forms a coherence space

$$
    \mathbf{1 \Rightarrow 1} = \{\emptyset, \{(\{0\}, 0)\}, \{(\emptyset, 0)\}\}
$$

Which, just like $\mathbf{Bool}$, has two incoherent tokens.  As far as I can see, the two should be equivalent, and there exists a stable function of type $\mathbf{(1 \Rightarrow 1) \Rightarrow Bool}$ which maps $F_2$ to $f$ and $F_3$ to $t$.

Can this function be expressed in the lambda calculus?  If not, why is it part of the interpretation?  Can we see $\mathbf{Bool}$ and $\mathbf{1 \Rightarrow 1}$ as "the same" due to the similarity in coherence space?

Comment: If you take a naive set-theoretic semantics interpreting 1 by a singleton set and Bool by a two-element set, then clearly 1 ⇒ 1 is not isomorphic to Bool anymore. The isomorphism here is a contingent feature of the coherence space model, corresponding to the fact that the two functions λx.x and λx.() (where () : 1) can be distinguished in this model by passing an empty clique (morally, an "undefined element") as argument.